# Django: Display database information to match the form? ValueError: .. didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, database, forms, filter, valueerror

I am trying to query the database to display results from the form. Once I select the form drop-down fields for my wanted query e.g. Ford C-Max 2019 1.2 Petrol 1500 , from which I coded for now to display results (regardless of Make & Model as I only have one atm) , then instead of showing me the table with matched results I get this error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view app.views.data didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

However I do have that result in the database table named ford_cmax (ignore the average & entered columns)

```
average entered             year  liter  fuel    mileage
9701    2020-04-08 20:59:45 2019  1.2    Petrol  1500
```

I did not have this problem before, the table showed all results fine before I did the tweaking for filters.

My code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Average, Query
from .forms import QueryForm

class QueryMakeModel(FormView):
        template_name = 'QueryMakeModel.html'
        success_url = '/data/'
        form_class = QueryForm

        def form_valid(self, form):
            return HttpResponse("Sweet.")

def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        FormSite = QueryForm(request.POST)
        if FormSite.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        FormSite = QueryForm()

    return render(request, 'app/QueryMakeModel.html', {'FormSite': FormSite})

def data(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query= request.GET.get('q')

        if query is not None:
            lookups= Q(mileage__icontains= query) & Q(fuel__icontains=query) & Q(liter__icontains=query) & Q(year__icontains=query)

            results= Average.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()

            context = { 'results': results}

            return render(request, 'app/db.html', context)
```

db.html (Data display page)

```
table>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Liter</th>
            <th>Fuel</th>
            <th>Mileage</th>
            <th>Average</th>
            <th>Entered</th>
        </tr>
        {% for Average in query_results %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ Average.year }}</td>
            <td>{{ Average.liter }}</td>
            <td>{{ Average.fuel }}</td>
            <td>{{ Average.mileage }}</td>
            <td>{{ Average.average }}</td>
            <td>{{ Average.entered }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

QueryMakeModel.html (Main Query Form Page)

```
{% block content %}

    <p>Please fill the details below:</p>

    <form action="/data/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

        {{  FormSite.as_p }}

        <button type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> Query
        </button>

    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
class Query(models.Model):  
    MAKE    = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices=MAKES)
    MODEL   = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices=MODELS)
    YEAR    = models.IntegerField(max_length = 4, choices=YEARS)
    LITER   = models.CharField(max_length = 3, choices=LITERS)
    FUEL    = models.CharField(max_length = 6, choices=FUELS)
    MILEAGE = models.IntegerField(max_length = 10, choices=MILEAGES)

class Average(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ford_cmax'

    average = models.IntegerField(max_length = 6)
    entered = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True)
    year    = models.IntegerField(max_length = 4)
    liter   = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
    fuel    = models.CharField(max_length = 6)
    mileage = models.IntegerField(max_length = 10)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from app import views
from django.conf.urls import include, url 
from app.views import QueryMakeModel

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='Index'),
    path('data/', views.data, name='Data')
]
```

Comment: Your code only catches get requests. At any other request the data method will be exited without returning anything - and hence the error.

Comment: @ger.s.brett ok how do I fix that?

Comment: Here is an example in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method

Comment: Still not solved after specifying. Someone help pls.

Answer (score 0):

am understand this  by non object in your form from viwes.py but just idea take this way because am not understand  your project !!

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.Query = self.request.Query
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: am put :    self.object.Query = self.request.Query                                                                   
  ///                                                 " Query " to say valid  this model from bdd

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: yes yes i mean  this erreur about  who object ! ?  you valid So put your object  ...     , my to talk  more if u want  https://twitter.com/ElgharbiSalah  or my fcb  https://www.facebook.com/Salahdineoron/

Answer (score 0):

See the last lines of this code:

```
def data(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query= request.GET.get('q')

        if query is not None:
            lookups= Q(mileage__icontains= query) & Q(fuel__icontains=query) & Q(liter__icontains=query) & Q(year__icontains=query)

            results= Average.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()

            context = { 'results': results}

            return render(request, 'app/db.html', context)

    else:  #you also have to return an HTTP response in this case
        return render(request, 'app/db.html', context)
```

Comment: With this I just get: local variable 'context' referenced before assignment.
When i remove the context from the last line it just displays an empty table and if I place it up before the if statements then it says it's referenced before assignment.

Comment: so the error is gone. Now you need to make sense of the last line: what do you want to do in case your view is called with a post request and not a get request?

Comment: Yes the error is gone, I changed everything from POST to GET, however I get either the full table displaying everything that's in it regardless of form inputs or empty table if i change something in the code. The filters aren't working for the form inputs. If i manually put in the value then it does work but I want the table to display results based on the form and that's what I need help with

Comment: Then start a new question - this is now a different topic.